# cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(“notificationID”)); what is the return...?

Tags: android, methods

cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(“notificationID”));

why we use of dot operator in between these methods? as cancel(int) method takes only one integer parameter.it has 3 methods as parametr.....what exactly the code will do..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try going through the concepts of object oriented programming first.

To answer your question, `getIntent()` returns an object of type intent. We call the `getExtras()` on the Intent object which returns an object of type Bundle. Then we call `getInt()` on the Bundle object to finally get the **int** we want to pass to the `cancel()` method.

The statement is equivalent to :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
int id = b.getInt("notificationID");
cancel(id);
```

If we don't need any of the intermediate objects, we can write the whole thing in a single line.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is a short way to write:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // or getIntent().getExtras();
int i = bundle.getInt(“notificationID”); // or getIntent().getExtras().getInt(“notificationID”);
cancel(i); // or cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(“notificationID”));
```

What you do is to invoke methods on the return value of each method.

Answer (score 0):

`cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(“notificationID”));`.. even here cancel is getting only 1 arguement... because.. `getIntent()= returns an intent` `intent.getExtras = returns the values it stores` if extras has some object then `.getInt(“notificationID”) = returns an Int value`.. So finally only thing remaining is integer...